# Associate OnClick of input type with C# method

Tags: c#, asp.net

On entering a text in a Textbox element in asp net, owed to the `OnTextChanged` attribute, the method `TextButton1_TextChanged` from code behind is triggered:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextButton1" runat="server" value="" OnTextChanged="TextButton1_TextChanged"> </asp:TextBox>`
```

What is a way to obtain the same functionality with an input type text like:

```
<input type="text" id="InputType1" placeholder="Placeholder here">
```

I tried this with no effect:

```
<input type="text" id="InputType1" onclick ="TextButton1_TextChanged" >
```

Comment: The simple answer: use a `TextBox`

Comment: This is really not trivial to do. Are you sure you really need that? Why not just use text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer: use a `TextBox`. But if you have to use the `HtmlInputText`-control you could handle the [`ServerChange`-event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.serverchange(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<input type="text" id="InputType1" runat="server" ServerChange="TextButton1_TextChanged" >
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Server_Change(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("You typed: " + InputType1.Value);
}
```

But note that you don't have `AutoPostBack`, so you have to wait until the next postback is triggered, f.e. from a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `runat="server"` and `OnServerClick="TextButton1_TextChanged"` if you want it to be an OnClick() equivalent or `OnServerChanged="TextButton1_TextChanged` for the textbox_change equivalent.
Link for more details about OnServerChanged:
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.onserverchange(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The person asked for an onclick equivalent. I provided that.. I also gave the example to look for if he wanted a textbox reaction.